# Scroll to the top when I open the app (after N minutes)

Tags: feature-request, android-app, ios-app, android-app-feed, ios-app-feed

A frequent process:

1. Open the app
2. Think, "wtf? I answered that question yesterday."
3. Remember to scroll up
4. See new feed content preloaded (no refresh required)

I can see why it behaves this way. Sometimes I do want to pick up where I left off. (I probably always want that behavior if I come in from app switching as opposed to the home screen.) But once it's been a certain amount of time - one hour? Three hours? Twelve? - I probably am looking for new stuff.

Alternatively, put a little banner at the top reminding me that there's new stuff above. Current behavior just makes it look like nothing has changed in 24 hours.

Comment: I like the banner idea. Or a semi-random floaty thing like Google Plus. Or better yet, a banner.

Comment: Does this happen in the Android app? If not, might as well add that tag as well.

Comment: @ɥʇǝS No idea. Any Android folks care to weigh in?

Comment: If I could find where I misplaced mine...

Comment: I can confirm this happens on the Android app as well- It's confused me a number of times.

Comment: Since there are different teams for each app it's likely that one will be done before the other, so marking this as [meta-tag:status-half-completed] would look odd. Maybe better add separate request, clone of this one, for the android app? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Good point, but I'm not sure how best it should work - the Android and iOS teams are both part of one larger Mobile Team. I'll let them organize it however they want, especially since there are [plenty of posts with both tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios-app+android-app).

Comment: I like the banner idea, since we already have a similar UI throughout the app.  I don't like automatically scrolling to new content because I've used the Facebook app more than zero times.

Comment: I definitely want it to scroll me up at random every few minutes even when I haven't left the app and also put all the content in a different post, though, @BrianNickel!

Comment: @abbyhairboat Solved from an iOS perspective.  The android question should be split out so Kasra can track it separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a new alpha build out with a solution for the iPhone (iPad has a different update behavior right now).

When new content is loaded into the feed, one of two things will happen:

1. If you manually triggered a refresh by pulling **and** are at the top of the screen, it will scroll you up.
2. Otherwise, it will show you a banner: "***New items.*** Tap to view."

   [image: Feed with "New Items" banner]

In the case of 2,

- Tapping the banner will cause it to scroll to the top of the feed.
- Scrolling to the top of the feed will also dismiss the banner (instantly in case of scroll-to-top gesture, or when the topmost feed item appears on screen).

As a side benefit, I completely overhauled the refresh controller's intro and exit animations so they should be less fickle.